# Shared class library - MAUI and ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, maui, class-library

Is it possible to share a class library between a .NET MAUI app and an ASP.NET Core app?

I have an API and MAUI api that share the same model which I would like to put into a class library but I can't find a way to do it.

Comment: Yes.  Just use a .NET library project

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have worked.  I was trying to use a .net maui class library.  If you post an response I will mark it as the answer.